# Java - how to simplify my java

Tags: java, pojo, apache-commons-beanutils

I am writing some java code in the Spring Framework.

I've got two beans, person and person1. They have a slightly different structure, that is to say the variable names for each differ slightly.

I'm trying to copy the details from one bean to the other. I only want to copy the value if the value is not null. I've seen an API called BeanUtils, but this will copy it regardless if it is null or not.

Here's my code:

```
if (person != null) {
       if (person.getAddressDetails() != null) {
               if (person.getAddressDetails().getStreetNumber() != null) {
                       person1.getAddressDetails().setStreetNo(person.getAddressDetails().getStreetNumber());
               }

               if (person.getAddressDetails().getStreetName() != null) {
                       person1.getAddressDetails().setStreetName(person.getAddressDetails().getStreetName());
               }
       }

       if (person.getHomeDetails() != null) {
               if (person.getHomeDetails().getPhoneNumber() != null) {
                       person1.getHomeDetails().setSPhoneNo(person.getHomeDetails().getPhoneNumber());
               }
       }
}
```

I have about 40 nodes that need to be copied over and this would create so much ugly code. Does anyone have a better way to do this? maybe if i make a mapping or something and then loop through it? not sure.

If not, does anyone know if i can make BeanUtils run a copy without copying the null values?

Reason is that the second bean, person1, already has a bunch of values. I only want to overwrite that if there are new values to overwrite it with.

As usual the variables are part of a much larger system and I can't standardise the names.

Thanks

Comment: If all the values are defined by standard getter/setter methods, you could use reflection to find the fields and only perform the copy if the field was not null.  You'd be trading off if/else blocks for try/catch blocks and reflection code, however.

Comment: I'm not familiar with reflection, can you explain?

Comment: You don't explicitly say it, but am I correct in assuming person and person1 are instances of the same class?

Comment: They do explictly say that `person` and `person1` are **not** instances of the same class. **"They have a slightly different structure, that is to say the variable names for each differ slightly. "**

Comment: +1 for looking for an alternative solution rather than writing a bunch of boilerplate code that would be a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: @Jarrod, thanks appreciated your vote up. `person1` and `person` are different classes

Answer (score 5):

Approach the problem from the other direction, your source data object should not care about constraints or business logic requirement of your target object.

That would be **tight coupling** and that is bad, especially if you are using Spring, you are doing exactly what an IoC container such as Spring it trying to help you **not** do.

Put the `null checking` coding in your `setXXX()` methods of the target object, that is the correct place to handle a business rule if you don't ever want to set the target properties if the source property is `null`.

```
public setXXX(final String s)
{
  if (s == null) { // do nothing }
  else { this.xxx = s; }
}
```

then you could use whatever mapping strategy / library you want and not worry about the source data `null` status. Blindly setting properties and letting the target decide when to ignore the incoming `null`.

Comment: a) If there is a general business rule for overwriting non-null properties, which might be hard to generalize for a complex system; and b) adding that particular logic to an object persisted with ORM will eventually make your life hell if you try to merge().

Comment: they don't say anything about ORM or any of those concerns. I stand by my answer, the Class should decide what its `nullablity` is **not** and external entity, that is **tight coupling** and breaks encapsulation introduces **low cohesion** and makes debugging a nightmare. OOA best practices are **loose coupling** and **high cohesion** With terrible class names like `person` and `person1` I don't think the OP is really concerned about theoretical *enterprisey* concerns, they just want to map property data from one class to another with the least amount of code.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) might help you out.